# IDW interpolation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I want to obtain the quantity of precipitation for each municipality in Brazil on a given year. For that, I'm trying to use IDW interpolation on QGIS to interpolate the precipitation data from weather stations to municipality centroids. I have two shapefiles, one for the weather stations (with station long-lat and total precipitation data) and another with municipality polygons (from which I obtain the centroids). I'm new to QGIS, but I'm already able to perform an IDW interpolation for the entire map, but cannot find a way designate specific values to the centroids.

If that is possible on QGIS, how do I do it?

Comment: So do you have the output of your IDW algorithm and you want to assign the value of that to your municipality polygons?

Comment: You can use the "Zonal statistics" tool in the processing toolbox to calculate a number of statistics across each polygon, or, if you want to extract the underlying IDW value to the point you can use the Saga tool "Add raster values to points".